# Extracting data from scrolling table using Rvest

Tags: r, web-scraping, rvest

I am looking to extract all of the records from the table located at https://thearcfooty.com/2017/01/28/a-complete-history-of-the-afl/

The challenge I have is that it is a scrolling table (text shows at the bottom of the table that it contains 31,228 records:

```
Showing 1 to 10 of 31,228 entries
```

I am new to Rvest and tried the following after inspecting the table in Google Chrome:

```
library(rvest)
url <- "https://thearcfooty.com/2017/01/28/a-complete-history-of-the-afl/"

Table  <- url %>%
  read_html() %>%
  html_nodes(xpath= '//*[@id="table_1"]') %>%
  html_table()
TableNew <- Table[[1]]
TableNew
```

But it just hangs continuously. Ideally, I would like to return a data frame with all of the records from all rows and all columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is some code inside `html_table` is a bit slow that why it runs endless. Actually you can read into all text and transform into dataframe shape. I haven't checked whether the result is correct. But based on my eyeballing a few examples, it should be fine.

```r
library(rvest)
#> Loading required package: xml2
library(data.table)
url <- "https://thearcfooty.com/2017/01/28/a-complete-history-of-the-afl/"

page <- read_html(url)

tb_str <- page %>% 
  html_nodes(css = 'tr') %>% 
  html_text()

dt <- data.table(raw=tb_str)

headers <- strsplit(tb_str[1],split = "\\W+")[[1]]
dt[,(headers):=tstrsplit(raw,split="\n +")]
dt[,raw:=NULL]
str(dt[!is.na(season)])
#> Classes 'data.table' and 'data.frame':   31228 obs. of  14 variables:
#>  $ date             : chr  "08/05/1897" "08/05/1897" "08/05/1897" "08/05/1897" ...
#>  $ season           : chr  "1897" "1897" "1897" "1897" ...
#>  $ round            : chr  "1" "1" "1" "1" ...
#>  $ home_away        : chr  "A" "A" "A" "A" ...
#>  $ team             : chr  "CA" "SK" "ME" "ES" ...
#>  $ opponent         : chr  "FI" "CW" "SY" "GE" ...
#>  $ margin_pred      : chr  "0.00" "0.00" "0.00" "-2.99" ...
#>  $ margin_actual    : chr  "-33.00" "-25.00" "17.00" "23.00" ...
#>  $ win_prob         : chr  "0.50" "0.50" "0.50" "0.47" ...
#>  $ result           : chr  "0.18" "0.24" "0.69" "0.74" ...
#>  $ team_elo_pre     : chr  "1500" "1500" "1500" "1500" ...
#>  $ opponent_elo_pre : chr  "1500" "1500" "1500" "1500" ...
#>  $ team_elo_post    : chr  "1473" "1478" "1515" "1522" ...
#>  $ opponent_elo_post: chr  "1526" "1521" "1484" "1477" ...
#>  - attr(*, ".internal.selfref")=<externalptr>
```

<sup>Created on 2020-07-27 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: accepting this answer as it was most helpful in resolving my issue.